# Login Endpoint not working on my machine, but it does elsewhere

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, token

Ok, so at this point I am very curious and I would love to find out what is wrong with my code or machine. I am working on a team project; I am part of the back-end with someone else; we started testing endpoints and they all work, except for me the `/api/auth/login` endpoint. Insommia gives me a 500 fatal error, with no message. The thing is , the exact same code , when cloned in another person's computer works.

I went ahead, and even deleted my local repository and created a new one and I am still getting the error. I have no idea what is going on. The project is a NodeJs Express Back End application.
Here is the repo in case someone wants to test it out for themselves. Funny thing, the deployed version of the api, works perfectly , including log in.

https://github.com/Build-Week-Secret-Family-Recipes-2/Back-End

[image]

Here is my auth router code for login

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    let { username, password } = req.body;

    Users.findByFilter({ username })
        .first()
        .then((user) => {
            if (user && bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) {
                
                const token = signToken(user);      
                res.status(200).json({
                    token: token,
                    message: `Welcome ${user.username}!`,
                });
            } else {
                res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid Credentials' });
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.status(500).json(err);
        });
});

function signToken(user) {
    const payload = {
        username: user.username,
    };
    const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET || 'it is a secret, is it safe?';
    const options = {
        expiresIn: '1h',
    };
    return jwt.sign(payload, secret, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, guys, I finally found out what the problem was. The reason the code was working for everyone but me, it is because I had the header type turned off in Insomnia. So it was not receiving a JSON object.

[image]